# SQL Server --> EDI X12 flat-file

Tags: sql-server, x12

How do I export data from SQL into a flat file EDI x12 document?

Is there more than one way?

Thanks!

Comment: You use a translator.  That's the best way.

Comment: No..a universal data translator.  A mapper will help you with the intricacies of the X12, like enveloping, 997 reconciliation, etc.

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server, it'd make sense to look at BizTalk for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools and tool kits targeted at moving data from SQL to X12 files and back.  It depends a lot on your enviroment.  Rolling your own solution can be very time consuming.  Buying an app to help you with the mappings can save a lot of time but are generally expensive and can be limiting.

DataJunction and BizTalk are a couple systems that I have used.  We ended up rolling our own solution to get past limitations and performance issues with off the shelf solutions.